# CSS font-face not working on phone

Tags: css, font-face

can anyone help with my CSS please? I am trying to locally pack my font into my website so it's downloaded by devices that don't support it, but it's not working. Here is what I've tried:

```
body {
     background-color: black;
     font-family: "century gothic";
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'century gothic';
  src: url('../font/GOTHIC.TTF')  format('truetype'),
       url('../font/GOTHIC.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../font/GOTHIC.woff2') format('woff2'),
}
```

To my understanding, in my body I'm setting the font as century gothic, which is fine for devices like my PC that have the font pre installed.

When I try to view the website on my phone, it's not being downloaded and displayed, it's just displaying the default HTML font. Times New Roman I believe.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: semi colon at end? or missing eot font?  fonts in wrong folder?

Comment: I'm guessing it's either a typo in the URL or the path isn't correct. Pete could be right that you have a `,` at the end of the `src` instead of a `;`.